# Match API and isomorphic routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have an isomorphic app running on express:

```
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match(
      { routes, location: req.url }, 
      (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => { ... }
```

Currently I'm matching on the wildcard as this is the approach I've seen taken in most boilerplates and tutorials I've seen.

This issue is now that I need to be able to match specific routes such as `/auth` and `/api` which need to be handled differently to the routes for the isomorphic app. i.e. the `/auth` route needs to authenticate a user.

I need a way to be able to specify those routes but then still maintain the wildcard matching for the routes used my the isomorphic app.

I've considered that instead of using a wildcard matcher I could collect all of the routes for the isomorphic app in to an array and provide that to express instead:

```
const isoRoutes = ['/home', '/about'];
app.get([isoRoutes], (req, res))
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to achieve this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `/auth` and `/api` routes aren't serving pages from your app (i.e. you're using them for AJAX calls), you should have separate request handlers for them.

As long as you specify the non-wildcard routes ahead of the wildcard `get`, you should be fine with the wildcard.

```
app.get('/auth', handleAuth);
app.get('/api', handleAPI);
app.get('*', handleRender);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code like this:-

```
req.url.match(//regular expression);
```

Match() only works with a regular expression.

Comment: So you mean keep the wildcard match and use `req.url.match` inside the callback to deal with the requests to `api`?